# Prove that $\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ for prime $p$

Tags: totient-function

Let $p$ be a positive prime, and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ (Euler's totient)

I suppose maybe induction should be involved. But I'm having difficulty relating $p^k$'s prime factors to $p^{k-1}$ prime factors exactly. I suppose that for example, $p^2$'s factors are those that are multiples of $p$'s factors. But how do I know that the numbers bigger than $p$ that are factors of $p^2$ add with the factors of $p$ to equal $p$? Sorry, does that even make sense?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144324/new-elegant-proofs-for-varphipk-pk-pk-1

Comment: Induction isn’t needed.  How many numbers up to $p^k$?   How many multiples of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Make a list of all the numbers between $1$ and $p^k$. 
$$1,2,3,4,\ldots, p^k$$

- How many numbers are there on this list?

  > There are $p^k$ numbers on the list.
- How many numbers have a common factor with $p^k$?

  > Since $p$ is a prime another number will have a common factor with $p^k$ if and only if $p$ divides it. These numbers are $$p\cdot \color{green}{1}, p\cdot \color{green}{2}, p\cdot \color{green}{3}, \ldots, p\cdot \color{green}{p^{k-1}}$$ There are $p^{k-1}$ such numbers.
- How many numbers does not have a common factor with $p^k$? (This is $\phi(p^k)$)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for the definition of prime number, a number $n$ is coprime with $p^k$ if and only if $p$ doesn't divide $n$. Since there are $\frac{p^k}{p}=p^{k-1}$ multiples of $p$ then:

$$\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$$