# Number of multiples of p less than $p^k$ for p prime

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I am trying to understand this proof:
[Prove that $\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ for prime $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201004/prove-that-varphipk-pk-pk-1-for-prime-p)

At some point it is stated that the number of multiples of p in range $[1,p^k)$ is $p^{k-1}$.
I am struggling to get why. I tried this:
The multiples of p are :
$$p, 2p, .., (p-1)p, p^2, 2p^2, .., (p-1)p^2, .., p^{k-1}, 2p^{k-1}, .., (p-1)p^{k-1}$$

Now I can think in terms of powers of p : Each power $p^i$ contributes $p-1$
mutliples : $$p^i, 2p^i, .., (p-1)p^i$$

And we have $k-1$ distinct powers so $(k-1)\times (p-1)$ multiples of p in total.
Of course that's really different from the actual result.
I cannot see what I am missing here.

Comment: Forget about prime powers for the moment. How would you calculate for example how many multiples of 7 there are below 1000?

Comment: By the way, in the link they are looking at multiples of $p$ in the range $[1,p^k]$, not $[1,p^k)$, so the list should end with $p^k$ itself.

Comment: I guess $\lfloor 1000/7 \rfloor-1$?

Comment: @tonythestark why do you need a $-1$ when you already have the floor function?

Comment: I was thinking that for example how many multiples of 2 are below 10 ?
10/2=5 but below 10 are only 4 : 2, 4, 6, 8

Comment: The number of multiples of $k$ in $[1,n]$ is $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$. So the answer to my question would be $\lfloor \frac{999}{7} \rfloor$. This happens to be the same as $\lfloor \frac{1000}{7} \rfloor$ since $1000$ is not itself a multiple of $7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything less than or equal to $p^{k-1}$ can be multiplied by $p$ and not go over $p^k.$

So there's exactly $p^{k-1}$ non-totatives.

Subtract those out to get $p^k-p^{k-1}$ totatives.

Comment: thank you I think I can get it if I think of it like that

Answer (score 3):

Your powers-based counting only counts those numbers that are "pure" powers of $p$ – those numbers that when written in base $p$ have only one nonzero digit. Your counting omits numbers like $p+p^2$.

---

Ellipses can also deceive you. Did you notice when writing
$$p, 2p, .., (p-1)p, p^2, 2p^2, .., (p-1)p^2, .., p^{k-1}, 2p^{k-1}, .., (p-1)p^{k-1}$$
that the separation between, say, $p^2$ and $2p^2$ is greater than $p$? This means there are more multiples of $p$ in between them.

Comment: yes you are right, I missed those